# Unable to set the visible property of the worksheet class

Tags: vba, excel

Very peculiar behavior being exhibited by Excel with regards to the subject error message. It's not the well known Protected Workbook issue as I've protected and unprotected the WB just to rule out that potential issue AND `Workbook.ProtectStructure` and `Workbook.ProtectWindows` are both `False`. The WB has no Pivot nor Chart related objects so that's not it either. Nor does it have only one remaining sheet that is Visible. In fact, the error occurs when attempting to hide any of the 20 sheets via code.

The code below pulls data from a table, named `ProtectedSheets`, of tab names and visibility settings `[-1, 0, 2]` for how to set the Visibility of that tab in the `Workbook_Close` method. As the developer of the Excel app I'm attempting to hide specific tabs that contain internal App data that the User does not need to mess with.

```
Dim LO As ListObject: Set LO = [ProtectedSheets].ListObject
Dim LR As ListRow
Dim c1 As Range
Dim c2 As Range

For Each LR In LO.ListRows
  With LR.Range
     Set c1 = .Cells(LO.ListColumns("SheetName").Index)
     Set c2 = .Cells(LO.ListColumns("Visibility").Index)
     Worksheets(c1.text).Visible = c2
     protectWS c1.text, True
  End With
Next LR
```

Upon executing the code line containing the `Visible` property, Excel produces the subject error message. Now here's the rub. If the WS is added as a Watch item its Visible property can be edited in the Watch pane without generating an error. Similarly, the Visible property can likewise be changed in the Immediate pane without generating the error. However, it stalls in the Debug pane. Hmm...

To add even more peculiarity, in the Watch and Immediate panes I found I had to pass the Visible property thru `0|xlSheetHidden` when attempting to change from `2|xlSheetVeryHidden` to `-1|xlSheetVisible`. By contrast, going the reverse direction from `xlSheetVisible` to `xlSheetVeryHidden` directly did not generate the error. However, attempts to duplicate this passing thru 0 in code failed to yield that same allowance and generates the error. I find there is much inconsistency with the behavior of this property. Any insights into what going on here are appreciated.

Comment: Works for me using `Worksheets(c1.text).Visible = c2.Value` instead of hoping that `VBA` uses `Range` value property per default.

Comment: TY for confirming the integrity of the code on your system. That tells me that the issue is local rather than a bug inherent in the property implementation. I am still curious about the differences in behavior when using the Watch and Immediate panes of the VBE as opposed to how the code normally executes in the editor.

Comment: While the VBE behavior remains a curiosity, I found your correction to be the solution to prevent the error from being thrown. Pointing to the c2 'Value' rather than the c2 cell cured what was ailing here. DOH!

Comment: `Worksheets(c1.text).Visible = c2.Value`